# What mean : $R^x$ is the probability that $Y_t$ start at $x$?

Tags: probability

Here the context :[image]

I'm a bit confuse by the notation, since he defines $Y_t=Y_t^x$, and at the bottom, he says that $R^x$ is the probability that $Y_t$ start at $x$, and after he writes
$$R^x(Y_{t_1}\in F_1,...,Y_{t_n}\in F_n)=P^0(Y_{t_1}^x\in F_1,...,Y_{t_n}^x\in F_n),$$
and really have to admit that it's a bit confusing. What does he mean by $R^x(Y_{t_1}\in F_1)=P^0(Y_{t_1}^x\in F_1)$ since $Y_{t_1}=Y_{t_1}^x$ by definition. Maybe $R^x(Y_{t_1}\in F_1)$ should be interpreted as $P(Y_{t_1}\in F_1\mid Y_{0}=x)$ ? But this would be $0$ if $P(Y_{0}=x)=0$. Can someone explain a bit ?

---

For example, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_diffusion#Sample_continuity) they say that $\mathbb P^x$ is the law of the process $X$ given initial datum $X_0=x$. Does it mean that $\mathbb P^x(X_{t_1}\in F_1,...,X_{t_n}\in F_n):=\mathbb P^x(X_{t_1}\in F_1,...,X_{t_n}\in F_n\mid X_0=x)$ ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the author was inventing some cumbersome notation so that he could use the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to represent the derivative of $f$ without confusing that $x$ with the $x$ in $Y^x_t$.

Using the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial  q}$ instead, the statement can be formulated in manner that is hopefully more comprehensible:

$$E[f(Y^x_t)]=E\left[\int_0^{\tau} \left( \sum_i u_i(s,w) \frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}(Y^x_s) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(vv^T)_{i,j}(s,w) \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial q_i \partial q_j} (Y^x_s) \right) \mathrm{d}s \right]$$